# How to prove that a polynomial is bounded below

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Show that if

$$P(z) = {a_n}z^{n} + {a_{n-1}}z^{n-1} + ... + {a_1}z + {a_0},$$

is a polynomial of degree $n$ then there is ${R_0} > 0$ such that for $|z| > {R_0}$ the polynomial can be bounded below as

$$|P(z)| > \frac{1}{2}|{a_n}||z|^{n}.$$

How do I have to start this proof?

Comment: $P(z)=a_nz^n\left(1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_nz}+...+\frac{a_0}{a_nz^n}\right)$ and $\frac{a_i}{a_n z^k}\to 0$ when $|z|\to \infty $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with the triangle inequality:

$$|P(z)|\geq |a_n||z|^n-|a_{n-1}||z|^{n-1}-\cdots-|a_0|$$
so that
$$|P(z)|\geq |a_n||z|^n\left(1-\dfrac{|a_{n-1}|}{|z|}-\cdots-\dfrac{|a_0|}{|z|^n}\right)$$
so we just need to show that 
$$\dfrac{|a_{n-1}|}{|z|}+\cdots+\dfrac{|a_0|}{|z|^n}\leq\dfrac{1}{2}$$
if $|z|$ is sufficiently large. But this holds since
$$\lim_{|z|\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{|a_{n-1}|}{|z|}+\cdots+\dfrac{|a_0|}{|z|^n}=0$$
You might want to formalize that last bit with $\varepsilon$ and $R_0$ depending how rigorous your proof needs to be.

Comment: I shall try to start, the proof needs to be very precisely by the way, but thanks!